# How to restrict Http redirection to Https for specific directory?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I am redirecting users from Http to Https, it is working fine, but client's requirement is to skip one directory for this.

For example: the user should not redirect to https if he access the following url: `www.example.com/ads`, but it should redirect if he access any other URL.

Here is the code I am using currently:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Well what you are using isn't PHP ! but if your apache redirect allow you, you can easily use header in PHP.

Comment: You can try something like `RewriteRule !^ads($|/) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`

Comment: You can also add exception in your apache config before your redirect rule : RewriteCond  %{REQUEST_URI}  !^/(ads)

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

```
RewriteRule !^ads($|/) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Try: `RewriteRule !^/?ads($|/) https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]` as your first rule and clear browser cache for testing.

Comment: @anubhava by adding the rule given by you, i am getting a "not found" error. Again i want to explain that i need to apply redirect 301 on whole directories of my website except "ads" folder means "ads" folder must be accessed like http://www.example.com/ads/ & whole website like "https://www.example.com".
Hope now my point is clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can add rewrite conditions for rewrite rule, and redirect will be performed only when they are met.

In your case you need first rule to check whether current request is not being done with https (To not to make an infinite redirect to same uri) and second for request uri and optionally host rule (In case you are using multiple host names, otherwise you can skip it). This code should work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com

    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:PORT} !^443$ #Some other variants are available , but I prefer this one because not all work well on different environments
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/ads$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

All awailable variables and other code snippets can be found on [official documentation page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have a .htaccess in `ads/` sub-directory.

Have your exclusion rule like this using `THE_REQUEST` variable:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName example.com
   ServerAlias www.example.com

   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !\s/+ads [NC]
   RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
```

Don't forget to restart Apache and completely clear your browser cache.

Comment: i tried this, it didn't redirect to https which is fine, but now it is showing an error of Page Not Found, any idea?

Comment: If it didn't redirect that means rule didn't execute as expected. After that 404 is something that is happening outside this rule since rule got skipped. Is `http://www.example.com/ads/` causing 404?

Comment: this url works if i undo the changes given by you, any idea?

Comment: Comment out `RewriteCond` line and then retest with same `http://www.rentown.net/ads/mbl/formland/001/a_opt/`

Comment: btw I am getting `https://www.rentown.net/ads/mbl/formland/001/a_opt/` as well which is not affected by above rule.

Comment: yes by commenting out that line, now it's again redirecting me to https

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/138720/discussion-between-anubhava-and-insomania).